# Passing variadic arguments as an array in Swift

Tags: swift, variadic-functions

Java 5+ allows passing variadic arguments either as an array, or individually. I expected Swift to allow passing variadic arguments as an array as well, but have no luck so far.

Here is a sample program, I tried in a playground. It creates an array of `CVarArg` and passes it to `String(format:...)`

```
let printData: [(format: String, param: [CVarArg])] =
    [(format: "This is blank", param: []),
     (format: "This is %@ %@", param: ["Swift", "language"])
   ]

for index in 0...1  {
    let pdata = printData[index]
    print (String(index+1) + " " + String(format: pdata.format, pdata.param))
}
```

I expected:

```
1 This is blank
2 This is Swift language
```

Instead it prints:

```
1 This is blank
2 This is (
    Swift,
    language
) (null)
```

Tried  using CVarArg... as a type:

```
let printData: [(format: String, param: CVarArg...)]
```

or bridging to CVarArg... :

```
String(format: pdata.format, pdata.param as CVarArg...)
```

In both cases I get compilation errors.

Is there a way to change the syntax of the above code to allow interpreting [CVarArg] in the expected way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem is that tuples do not support variadic arguments. So

```
 (format: "This is %@ %@", param: ["Swift", "language"])
```

is a tuple of two things: a string and an array and `String(format:,_)` sees the array as only one object. To solve your immediate problem, use [`String(format:,arguments:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/3126743-init). e.g.

```
for index in 0...1  {
    let pdata = printData[index]
    print (String(index+1) + " " + String(format: pdata.format, arguments: pdata.param))
}
```

Given how easy it is to create a literal array, I'd question the need to use variadic arguments anywhere in Swift.

Comment: Good approach for String(format:..), but no answer in general.  As about the need of variadic arguments, just a matter of convenience: no need to place square brackets.

Comment: @cyanide If it was all about saving key strokes, we'd all be programming in APL. There was a big argument a few years ago on Swift Evolution about whether variadic arguments should be removed. At the time I was in favour of retaining them but but they are not necessary. In the end they were retained for backwards compatibility and interfacing with C APIs. I guess one argument in favour is that the compiler can check them for compatibility with the format string. It doesn't work for your use case though.